# Overlay graphs wiht different colors using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this two graphs and I need overlay them with two differents colors.

```
a <- matrix(c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1), ncol = 2 ,byrow = T)
b <- .5*matrix(c(0,0,1,0,1,1), ncol = 2 ,byrow = T)
p1 <- ggplot()
p1 <- p1 + geom_polygon(data = data.frame(a), aes(a[,1], a[,2]), fill = NA, col = "black") 
p2 <- ggplot()
p2 <- p2 + geom_polygon(data = data.frame(b), aes(b[,1], b[,2]), fill = NA, col = "red") 
p2
```

Comment: Please provide some reproducible data.

Comment: Do you mean plot them both on the same plot? Just add all the layers to the same plot: `ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = data.frame(a), aes(a[,1], a[,2]), fill = NA, col = "black") + geom_polygon(data = data.frame(b), aes(b[,1], b[,2]), fill = NA, col = "red") `

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem, thanks.